# Updating a wp_postmeta field not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I cannot update a wp_postmeta field called 'alive_days' and making its value equal to zero, in wordpress. I have tried all the two following solutions but still not working:

> 1. $alive_days='alive_days';$mypostid=$_REQUEST['pid'];
> 2. global $wpdb;
> 3. $wpdb->query("update
>      $wpdb->wp_postmeta set meta_value==\"$ziro\" where
>      post_id=\"$mypostid\" and meta_key=\"$alive_days\"");

1. $ziro=0;
2. $mypostid=$_REQUEST['pid'];
3. update_post_meta($mypostid, 'alive_days',$ziro);

The field value will not change after the execution.

Comment: How about this: if ( ! add_post_meta( $mypostid, 'alive_days', $ziro ) ) { update_post_meta ( $mypostid, 'alive_days', $ziro ); } .

Comment: This solution didn't work,

Comment: At what point are you trying to change the meta data? Where is your code running?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
update_post_meta( $post_id,'alive_days', 0 );
```